# Highchart showing up empty until button click

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, highcharts

I have been customizing the following jsfiddle in order to display data from a database.  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7ntyzo6u/

I am using JSON in order to retrieve data in my database. In the jsfiddle, there are 3 charts which can be switched between by clicking buttons. But when you load the page, chart1 is the default chart showing. Now I have edited chart1 so that it will display my database data:

```
var chart,
  chartOptions = {},
  chartData = {};

chartData.chart2 = randomData(10, true);
chartData.chart3 = randomData(65, true, 300);

chartOptions.chart1 = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Chart 1 Title'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: []
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart 1<br/>Y Axis'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Chart 1 Series',
    data: []
  }]
};
var tableName = '<?php echo $tableName; ?>'
$.getJSON("../../companies/charts/Data.php", {id: escape(tableName)}, function(json) {
    chartOptions.chart1.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
    chartOptions.chart1.series[0].data = json[6]['data'];
});
```

My problem is, that the chart shows up as empty after loading the page. Only when I click the chart1 button will the data show up. Can anyone tell me if this is because I am missing something after setting the xAxis and series data in the above code?

Since $.getJSON is asynchronous (see comment below) I have tried to now send the request using ajax instead. Below is my attempt, but this is flawed since the chart will now not even display data upon clicking the 'chart1' button. The chart does come up, but is empty:

```
chartOptions.chart1 = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Chart 1 Title'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: []
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Chart 1<br/>Y Axis'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Chart 1 Series',
    data: []
  }]
};
var tableName = '<?php echo $tableName; ?>'
$.ajax({
  url: "../../companies/charts/Data.php",
  data: {id: escape(tableName)},
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  succes: function(data) {
  chartOptions.chart1.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
  chartOptions.chart1.series[0].data = json[6]['data'];
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that since `$.getJSON` is asynchronous , the chart is already loaded before the data is populated.
You can try calling the setData method on the series inside the $.getJSON block.This will force a chart redraw :

```
chartOptions.chart1.series[0].setData(json[6]['data'],true);
```

Or try to send the request using `$.ajax` with `async:false`.Replace the following block with the $.getJSON block.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "../../companies/charts/Data.php",
  data: {id: escape(tableName)},
  async:false
}).done(function() {
  chartOptions.chart1.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
  chartOptions.chart1.series[0].data = json[6]['data'];
});
```

I think this should get you going.

Read more about it over here: [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it out, but unfortunately the only change this does is that the data now won't even show when I click the button. I am sure you are right in that the chart don't get populated because of the $.getJSON.

Comment: Oh! Bummer. Try using `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON` with `async:false` so that the request will be completed synchronously.

Comment: I would like to try this approach but I have never used the ajax approach before (in general I am quite a newbee to this). You will notice that I am using a variable passed into Data.php in order to retrieve the data in a JSON array. Can you help me with how I would do this in Ajax?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! I tried to implement your code but this unfortunately stops the charts from displaying altogether. I then tried to read through the link you provided and looked up a lot of questions on ajax+highcharts and have now edited your suggestion a bit (see my edited question). The charts will display now but the chart1 will not display data from my database - not even upon clicking the button.